# Best JS library to use to create a particle network in the shape of a svg image?

Tags: javascript, web-development

I would like to create a particle network in the shape of a svg 
(or png) image I have on a website. The particles should be animated and look/behave like particle.js linked particles but should take the shape/be limited by the shape of a svg I have.

I think maybe three.js or particle.js with an alpha mask could work but I haven't been having much success with finding examples of them forming shapes from given svg images.

Something like [this](https://peterbeshai.com/blog/2017-05-26-beautifully-animate-points-with-webgl-and-regl/) would be nice but in the shape of any svg and the particles would be linked.

Thanks!